# QCursor::setPos() does not work when moving the mouse

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to lock the mouse in the widget, for this I constantly set the mouse position in the center of the widget, and to move the camera in my scene I use the virtual cursor position.

```
void MainOpenGLWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    virtualMousePosition = this->rect().center();
    qInfo() << "press event:";
    qInfo() << "real mouse position:" << event->pos();
    qInfo() << "virtual mouse position:" << virtualMousePosition;
    setCursor(Qt::BlankCursor);
    QCursor::setPos(mapToGlobal(this->rect().center()));
    QMouseEvent eventCopy(event->type(), virtualMousePosition, event->button(), event->buttons(), event->modifiers());
    sceneManager->callMousePressEventHandler(eventCopy);
}

void MainOpenGLWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    //"Note that the returned value(event::button()) is always Qt::NoButton for mouse move events."

    if (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton && event->pos() != rect().center())
    {
        virtualMousePosition += (event->pos() - rect().center());
        qInfo() << "move event:";
        qInfo() << "real mouse position:" << event->pos();
        qInfo() << "virtual mouse position:" << virtualMousePosition;
        QMouseEvent eventCopy(event->type(), virtualMousePosition, event->button(), event->buttons(), event->modifiers());
        sceneManager->callMouseMoveEventHandler(eventCopy);
        QCursor::setPos(mapToGlobal(this->rect().center()));
    }
}
```

So, what's the problem I'm facing?
I have two cases:

1. I click a button on the widget(I don't move the mouse at the time of clicking) and then start moving the mouse left and this is the output I get:

```
press event:
real mouse position: QPoint(504,308)
virtual mouse position: QPoint(359,340)
move event:
real mouse position: QPoint(358,340) <- All is fine, the mouse is in the center of the widget
virtual mouse position: QPoint(358,340)
move event:
real mouse position: QPoint(357,340)
virtual mouse position: QPoint(356,340)
move event:
real mouse position: QPoint(358,340)
virtual mouse position: QPoint(355,340)
move event:
real mouse position: QPoint(358,340)
virtual mouse position: QPoint(354,340)
move event:
real mouse position: QPoint(356,340)
virtual mouse position: QPoint(351,340)
```

2. I move the mouse to the left over the widget and press the mouse button while moving the mouse.
   Here's the output I get:

```
press event:
real mouse position: QPoint(638,309)
virtual mouse position: QPoint(359,340)
move event:
real mouse position: QPoint(637,309) <- Something went wrong, my mouse cursor didn't move to the center of the widget!
virtual mouse position: QPoint(637,309)
move event:
real mouse position: QPoint(634,309)
virtual mouse position: QPoint(912,278)
move event:
real mouse position: QPoint(356,340)
virtual mouse position: QPoint(909,278)
move event:
real mouse position: QPoint(358,340)
virtual mouse position: QPoint(908,278)
move event:
real mouse position: QPoint(355,340)
virtual mouse position: QPoint(904,278)
move event:
real mouse position: QPoint(357,340)
virtual mouse position: QPoint(902,278)
move event:
real mouse position: QPoint(358,340)
virtual mouse position: QPoint(901,278)
move event:
real mouse position: QPoint(356,340)
virtual mouse position: QPoint(898,278)
```

It turns out that if I press the button while moving the mouse, the cursor is not placed in the center and I have problems.
How can I avoid this?

Comment: Maybe you could solve your problem by storing the previous position and using the difference to the previous position for the virtual position? This way, it doesn't matter if recentering is off some times. You only need the recentering so that the mouse will not get stuck at a screen edge.

Comment: @ypnos, I'm not sure what you're talking about.
Please tell us more about it.